# Issue regarding merging of datasets

Tags: r, merge, dataset

Here I was using 2 datasets "dailyActivity_merged" and "sleepDay_merged" which had column names "ActivityDate" and "SleepDay" which had inputs of data in them, so i wanted to merge these datasets together by "Id" and "Date" after renaming the respective columns as "Date" as shown in the following code:

```
rename(dailyActivity_merged,Date=Avtivitydate)
rename(sleepDay_merged,Date=SleepDay)
merge(dailyActivity_merged,sleepDay_merged,by=c("Id","Date"),all.x=TRUE)
```

But I kept getting the following error:

```
Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column
```

I initially thought it was because of some inconsistency in "Id" but that was not the case as I ran the merge function without "Date" and it was running. If anyone could guide me here I would be grateful.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput` for each data set, something like `dput(head(df))`.

Comment: Did you assign the renamed data to a variable?

Comment: As hinted by Martin, `rename` (and most R functions) do not operate *in place*, that is, the object passed to the function is not modified, but a copy is created. You probably want `dailyActivity_merged <- rename(dailyActivity_merged,Date=Avtivitydate)` etc

Answer (score -1):

Use `full_join(df1,df2,by="Id")`
You don't even need to explicitly state by "id" but it's a good habbit.

Otherwise read documentation for inner-join and right_join
Install the tidyverse packages to make use of this code

Comment: The packages you are using are missing and `"I'd"` and `"id"` aren't the same.

Comment: It's the auto correct. Op should use the tidyverse packages. That is a bit of an obvious to me...

Comment: It's obvious to you since you know these packages but those aren't part of `base R`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example. Both issues mentioned in my comment could easily corrected.